# Dirac spinor field anti-commutation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices, anticommutator

I am thinking the anti-commutation property of Dirac field! First, note that the equal time anti-commutation relation (from P&S's QFT):
$$\{ \psi_a(\mathbf{x}),\psi_b^{\dagger}(\mathbf{y}) \}=\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})\delta_{ab} \tag{3.102}$$

Now if we consider following example:
$$\begin{aligned}\overline{\psi(x)}\gamma^{\mu}\psi(x)&=(\gamma^{\mu})^{ab}\overline{\psi_a(x)}\psi_b(x) \\
&=(\gamma^{\mu})^{ab}\psi_c^{\dagger}(x)(\gamma^0)^c_a\psi_b(x) \\
&=- (\gamma^{\mu})^{ab}\psi_b(x)\overline{\psi_a(x)} \end{aligned}$$
The last equality is from the off-diagonal property of Gamma matrices! Since $a\neq b$ and $a \neq c$ for non-zero components, so $b\neq c$, so switch $\psi_b(x)$ and $\psi_c^{\dagger}(x)$ only have a minus sign, don't have $\delta(0)$ term!

Would my analysis right?

---

EDIT:
When we considering the fermion loop calculation, I have seen many times about this exchange at same space time $x$ and only have a minus sign difference! Is their any deeper reason?

Comment: Not all gamma matrices are off-diagonal.  They are *traceless*, but in one popular basis $\gamma^0= {\rm diag}(1,1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you very much! But I also see people do this exchange, just have a minus sign! For example, when we calculate the fermion loop, and finally we have trace of green functions! So is there any deeper reason for this exchange of $\psi_a(x)$ and $\psi_b(x)$ to just have a minus sign difference?

Comment: I'm nit sure what you are getting at, but  one often omits the delta diveregences when computing vevs of currents.  I.e normal ordering,

Comment: @mikestone I see! Thank you very much! So could you please explain what's the meaning of vevs of currents?

Comment: Vevs= "vacuum expectation values"